# Keep getting application-defined or object-defined error, while i can't see what i did wrong

Tags: vba, excel

In my excel VBA code i wan't to copy from the sheet Calculatie to the sheet Gantt Chart, but when i wan't to paste to the cells in the Gantt Chart sheet i get an error. See code below.

Note that i used the "test" variable to see if i could get it working in an other way.

```
Sub setValue()
Dim test As String

gantCell = Sheets("Gantt Chart").Rows("5:1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
calcCell = gantCell - 3
formCell = gantCell + 1
Worksheets("Gantt Chart").Cells(gantCell, 6).Value = "1"
gantCellNext = Sheets("Gantt Chart").Rows("5:1000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
'code zoeken om alle cellen onder de 1e zichtbare cell de volgende formule te geven =rij 1 hoger dan de huidige cel + 1 rij en 1 kollum hoger
i = gantCell
test = "F" & i
MsgBox test
Sheets("Calculatie").Cells(calcCell, 2).Copy
Sheets("Gantt Chart").Range("test: F35").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply
MsgBox formCell
MsgBox gantCell
MsgBox calcCell

End Sub
```

Comment: change `Range("test: F35")` to `Range(test & ":F35")` or simply use `Range(test).PasteSpecial...`

Comment: Worked! thank you so much! setting this question to solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As follow up from comments, this one works:

```
Sheets("Gantt Chart").Range(test).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply
```

or

```
Sheets("Gantt Chart").Range(test & ":F35").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationMultiply
```